# How to install specific mongo version from the PPA?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-3.4

Once you've setup the offical mongo PPA, Mongo's [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) say that to install a specific version on Ubuntu, to run something like:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.2
```

I'd like to install version 3.4.10 on Ubuntu 16. I verified this version is available with:

```
apt-cache policy mongodb-org
```

which lists:

```
mongodb-org:
  Installed: 3.4.10
  Candidate: 3.4.11
  Version table:
     3.4.11 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.10 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.4.9 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.8 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.7 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.6 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.5 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.4 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.3 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.2 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.1 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.4.0 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

so I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.10
```

but I received this nonsensical output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,522 B/67.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 271 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org amd64 3.4.10 [3,522 B]
Fetched 3,522 B in 0s (8,901 B/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 84310 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_3.4.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (3.4.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.4.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.4.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.4.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.4.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.4.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.4.10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (3.4.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.4.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (3.4.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.4.10) ...
```

Why does it say it's installing 3.4.11...only to finally say it's setting up 3.4.10? When I run `/usr/bin/mongod --version` it indeed shows it's installed the wrong version.

```
db version v3.4.11
git version: 34f5bec2c9d827d71828fe858167f89a28b29a2a
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, to install a specific version, you need to specify not just the version of the main package, but also the version of all package dependencies. Otherwise apt-get assumes you want the most recent versions, of the dependencies...which require the most recent version of your main package, causing it to ignore your specified version. When I specified 3.4.10 for all the various mongo-org packages like:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.10 mongodb-org-server=3.4.10 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.10 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.10 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.10
```

then it correctly installed 3.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

As i am seeing you have type the syntax like that

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.2
```

Here i would like to say that if you want to install MongoDB version from **PPA**(Personal Package Archives) for Ubuntu then you can simply type `mongodb-org`. No need to mention as like

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.10
```

Because `PPA` is nothing but a non standard `software/updates`. So, always it take update version from their respective vendor organization, like that

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

In your case you want to install a specific version then definitely you have to define the version number (like MongoDB Version 3.4.10)

I am write down the simple steps to install **MongoDB 3.4** in **Ubuntu 16.04**.

1) First we will import the MongoDB GPG public key in our system using following command

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

The Ubuntu package management tools (i.e. dpkg and apt) ensure package consistency and authenticity by requiring that distributors sign packages with GPG keys.

2) Create a MongoDB list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with this command:

**For Ubuntu 16.04:**

```
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-3.4.list
```

3) Now that the MongoDB `repository` has been added, use following commands to install MongoDB in your systems.

Suppose that here in your case you want to install the specific version of MongoDB like **3.4.10** , then the command would be as mention below

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ apt-get install mongodb-org=3.4.1 mongodb-org-server=3.4.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.10
```

**Note: -** To installing the particular version repository, you make sure that you have run the `$ sudo apt-get update`.

**To install update stable version of MongoDB**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

4) Start `MongoDB` and add it as service to be started at boot time:

**For Ubuntu 16.04**:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongod
$ sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

5) Finally use the below command to check installed `MongoDB` version on your system

Type in the mongo shell command such as

```
$ mongod --version
```

You shall get the your specific installation of MongoDB version details.

> **Most Important :** The unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB. You should always use the official
>   MongoDB mongodb-org packages, which are kept up-to-date with the most
>   recent major and minor MongoDB releases.

For further your ref [Here](http://www.techoism.com/install-mongodb-3-4-ubuntu-16-0414-04/) and [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)